# Creating multiple pdfs (containing arabic/farsi language) using mpdf library with codeigniter,

Tags: php, codeigniter, pdf, utf-8, mpdf

I am using mpdf library to create multiple pdf files (which contain farsi words). Using php (codeigniter) and mpdf library. I generate the pdfs within a loop, however the first pdf is generated without any problem.
[firs generated pdf](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IgTb5.png)
but in the others the characters are isolated as [other pdf(s)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q9Uvm.png).  I searched several times and read the documentation of mpdf, but could not solve the problem. Any solution or suggestions, ...

```
$write_data .= "<!DOCTYPE html>
                        <html dir='rtl' lang='fa'>
                        <head>
                        <meta http-equiv='Content-Type' content='text/html; charset=utf-8'/>
                        <title></title></head><body><div>سلام</div></body></html>";
$this->load->library('m_pdf');
for($i=0;$i<3;$i++){
$m=new mPDF('utf-8');
$m=new mPDF('fa','A4','','',32,25,27,25,16,13);
$m->debug = true;
$m->SetDirectionality('rtl');
$m->mirrorMargins = true;
$m->WriteHTML($write_data);
$m->Output($path.'f'.$i.'.pdf', "F");//$path stores the path of the file
}
```

Comment: did you tried to change the charset?

Comment: Yes, I used : iconv('windows-1252', 'UTF-8', $write_data); and utf8_encode($write_data) but they could not solve the problem :(

Comment: its the project link : https://www.dropbox.com/s/kci5l7n9v9qyrc6/pdfs.zip?dl=0

Comment: try to set auofont function if it is working then you need to adjust the font http://mpdf1.com/manual/index.php?tid=252 http://mpdf1.com/manual/index.php?tid=347

Comment: tanx, yes, I changed <html dir='rtl' lang='fa'> to <html dir='rtl' lang='ar'>, and tried these functions and constants: $m->debug = true;
         $m->pregCURSchars = "\x{0590}-\x{083E}\x{0900}-\x{0DFF}\x{FB00}-\x{FDFD}\x{FE70}-\x{FEFF}";
         $m->baseScript = 9;
         $m->autoLangToFont=true;
         $m->rtlAsArabicFarsi = true;
        $m->text_input_as_HTML = true; 
        $m->useAdobeCJK = true;
$m->autoScriptToLang=true;
$m->autoLangToFont = true;
$m->autoArabic = true;
$m->allow_output_buffering = false; but still the first pdf is without any problem سلامbut the others:س ل ا م

Comment: Now it works fine, I used tcpdf library instate of mpdf library, mPDF does not work well....